# Repeat typed characters before a space

Tags: evil, keyboard-macros

Using Emacs with Evil Mode, I wonder if there's a way to quickly re-enter all the characters that were typed before a whitespace character is entered.

Example: you type `\hat{\beta}_{OLS,j}` and then you add a whitespace  , now you want to re-type `\hat{\beta}_{OLS,j}` automatically, so that in the end you have

`\hat{\beta}_{OLS,j} \hat{\beta}_{OLS,j}`

Example 2: you type `foo foo complicated_formula` and then enter a whitespace , now you want to retype `complicated_formula` automatically, so that in the end you obtain:

`foo foo complicated_formula complicated_formula`

How can I achieve this functionality? Is there something similar or better than this already available?

Thanks for helping me out! Keep in mind I'm extremely newb. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qayT pq` creates a macro 'a' that copies the text from the previous space to the cursor and then paste it. You can write a function the do this as well. And i think this should be a vim-related question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that also helps! However I'm looking for something that copies only the last typed characters up to a whitespace, not the entire phrase. I added another example to clarify my question. Thanks again for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé Then replace ^ with 'T ' is ok.